# WMIC Provider Load Failure When Called From Java (Windows 7)

Tags: java, wmic

On certain Windows 7 machines, when I call 'wmic csproduct get' from the command line, I get results as I should.  When I call this from a java runtime, it throws a "Provider Load Failure".  As of right now, it only seems to occur on Windows 7 machines, and not all Windows 7 machines.  Below is a sample program that produces the same result:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class TestMain {
private static String console(String string) {
    String result = ""; //$NON-NLS-1$
    String error = "";
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(string);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line + '\n';
        }
        input.close();

        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            error += line + '\n';
        }
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Unknown error occurred with command");//$NON-NLS-1$
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.err.println(error);
    return result.trim();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(TestMain.console("c:/windows/system32/wbem/wmic.exe csproduct get"));
}
}
```

A few more things:

1. This is running as a 32 bit program
2. I am using the wmic from the 32 bit folder
3. Only occurs on Windows 7, but not all Windows 7 systems